# Envío de una variable con AJAX a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente...
Tengo 3 archivos, 1 html, 1 php y 1 js

Dentro del html está lo siguiente:

```
 <div class="seccion1">
  <h3>Modelo</h3>
   <select id="modelo" name="modelo">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
   </select>
 </div>    
    
<div class="seccion4">
  <ul class="actions">
   <li><input type="button" id="generar" value="Genenerar plantilla" class="special" onclick="generarP()" style="border-radius: 5px;" /></li>
  </ul>
    
  <textarea id="Output" readonly="true"></textarea>
</div>
```

En el php tengo esto:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch($action) {
            case 'ejemplo' : ejemplo();break;
            case 'generar' : generarP();break;
        }
    }
function generarP() {
        $modelo= $_POST['modelo'];
        return $modelo;
    }
}
?>
```

y en el js esto:

```
function generarP() {
    const mod = document.getElementById("modelo");

    //Ningun servicio
    if (mod.value == "") {
        alert("Selecciona un modelo");
    } else
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://dominio/php/archivo.php',
        data: {action: 'generar', modelo: this.title },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = (output);
        }
    });
}
```

Sin embargo no logro que se visualice el valor, en la práctica voy a ocupar el modelo para el codigo de php y despues el resultado lo imprimiré en el textarea "output" :,(

Comment: recomendacones, tu post en la parte de html le falta codigo, tu php tiene el metodo ejemplo() que no existe en tu codigo ... por cierto el uso de ajax es para evitar tener que refrescar, estas redundando en tu post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el error, me faltó poner el `.value`

```javascript
const mod = document.getElementById("modelo").value;
```

Entonces el js queda de la sig forma:

```
function generarP() {
    const mod = document.getElementById("modelo").value;

    //Ningun servicio
    if (mod == "") {
        alert("Selecciona un modelo");
    } else
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://dominio/php/archivo.php',
        data: {action: 'generar', modelo: mod },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = (output);
        }
    });
}
```